# Тестирование оперативной памяти memtest86

Tags: железо, ram, пк

Достаточно ли одного стандартного прогона в **memtest86 4.3.7**, чтобы быть уверенным в надёжности и исправности всех планок оперативной памяти?
Если нет, то подскажите как более эффективно это сделать, нежели прогнать стандартный тест несколько раз?

**Дополнение.**
Я купил на [Алиэкспресс](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Brand-New-Sealed-DIMM-DDR2-800Mhz-2GB-PC2-6400-memory-for-Desktop-RAM-good-quality/32306380510.html) 4 планки китайской DDR2 800 2GB for AMD only.
Материнская плата у меня [Asus M2N32-SLI Deluxe](https://www.asus.com/ru/supportonly/M2N32-SLI%20Deluxe/HelpDesk_QVL/).
При первой установке 4-ёх планок у меня memtest86 показывал ошибки и зависал не завершая тесты, причём при разных запусках кол-во ошибок разное и зависания в разных местах.
[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После этого я вынул из слотов все, кроме 1 и провёл тест повторно, тест был пройден, добавил ещё 1, тест пройден, добавил, ещё 1 тест снова завис, подумал именно в этой планке дело, заменил её оставшейся, и тест с 3мя планками был пройден.
Подумал что всё, нащёл неисправную планку. Вынул все кроме неё и поставил её в ближайший к процессору слот, и поставил на тест, ожидая, что он покажет её неисправность, но тест был пройден!
Добавил ещё 1, чтобы протестировать в `dual mode 128bit`, тест пройден, добавил остальные 2, подумал уже что у меня проблема с материнской платой, но и тут тест был пройден!
Я поменял местами самую первую планку, которую считал проблемной с соседней, которая в том же канале, и снова поставил на тест... Тест пройден!

Может ли быть такое вообще, что все планки исправны и проблемная планка сбоила, например, из-за недостаточного усилия при установке, но при этом её полный объём был виден и суммирован с остальными, или из-за особого расположения планок в слотах, при том что на них одинаковые чипы, или тому подобное?

Оставил после первого удачного прогона, который занял чуть больше часа, но второй прогон занял почти 6 часов.[image: 5][image: 6]
Это так и должно быть?

Comment: _"Если нет, то подскажите как более эффективно это сделать, нежели прогнать стандартный тест несколько раз?"_ - убрать все планки, кроме одной исследуемой, и запустить тяжелую игру или стресс-тест в проге типа Sandra. Повторить для каждой планки. Memtest не дает никаких гарантий, нужно тестировать в реальных условиях. Если проблема только при нескольких установленных планках - дело в их несовместимости или не хватает напряжения для их совместной работы.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам интересно, на материнской плате Asus M2N-SlI Deluxe (не M2N32-SLI Deluxe) китайская память "для AMD" в планках по 2ГБ DDR2-800 работает, только если вставить 2 любых модуля. Добавление третьего вызывает неработоспособность. При этом все 4 планки памяти исправны и работают парой в ней в любых сочетаниях. А в какой-нибудь плате на чипсете AMD (770/790) с тем же процессором (и контроллером памяти) все четыре планки работают успешно. Вот такая странность, я вообще удивлён, что у вас на Nvidia удалось запустить 4 модуля. Запускаемость и работоспособность подобной памяти ещё сильно зависит от модели процессора, чем новее процессор, тем совместимее он с этой памятью. Например, старый Athlon 64 X2 4200+ может выдавать синие экраны с этой памятью, а новый Athlon II X2 250 - не иметь никаких проблем.

Если интересно, память "для AMD", бывает, заводится на чипсетах Nvidia для Intel, что тоже забавно. Но тоже со странными ограничениями, типа только один модуль или что ещё.

Answer (score 1):

Memtest обычно оставляют запущенным на ночь, но это в случаях когда компьютер глючит и есть подозрение на память. У вас же явная проблема с dual mode. Самое внятное объяснение которое я читал относительно такой памяти, в них используются чипы от северной памяти и родная частота для них 667 MHz, т.е. 800 это overclocking. Отсюда можно дать рекомендацию понизить частоту работы памяти. А в БИОС загрузить "Load Fail-Safe Defaults" настройки таймингов. Мне лично последнее помогло с такой памятью, когда Memtest ошибками сыпал.

PS Странное решение конечно брать память планками по 2GB. У меня две планки Kllisre по 4GB, материка Asus m3n78-vm на чипсете Nvidia gf8200, все работает. Не на максимальных таймингах конечно и есть проблемы совместимости с обычной памятью.

Comment: Странное решение конечно брать память планками по 2GB.

Я бы с удовольствием взял бы 4x4GB если бы моя материнка их поддерживала.

Comment: так, контроллер памяти у AMD находится в CPU, поддержка материнской платой тех или иных планок памяти ничего не значит. Главное что-бы процессор поддерживал.

Comment: И сколько, по-вашему, поддерживает озу AMD Athlon 64 x2 (Windsor 90 нм F3)? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_64_X2#Windsor_(90_%D0%BD%D0%BC_SOI)

Comment: Насколько понимаю, википедию и спецификации смотреть бесполезно, это не документируемая возможность. Контролёр памяти АMD имеет адресную шину с разрядностью увеличенной на один разряд. Поэтому на AMD можно ставить планки с памятью удвоеного объёма. На Intel такая память понятно что работать не будет. Про Athlon'ы ничего утверждать не буду. Проверял с phenom 8650.